# How to properly encode Google Geocode Api request

Tags: php, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

After encoding the address

65 1/2 Glen Street Glen Cove NY 11542

using  the urlencode(), here is the encoded address

65+1%2F2+Glen+Street+Glen+Cove+NY+11542

But when the API interprets this, It keeps changing the street to 1 Glen Street

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Funnily enough if you type that into maps.google.com you get this: https://www.google.com/maps/search/65+1%2F2+Glen+Street+Glen+Cove+NY+11542/@40.8636727,-73.6346559,16.84z - it doesn't think that it's an address. You encoded it correctly, it's just their actual address. If you try just "65 Glen Street"  it works. It's more of their API correcting your address because it doesn't think that 65 1/2 is a valid address.

Comment: I think you're wrong

Comment: @JonLuca thanks!! also do you think I should I remove the 1/2 off any address in the future? Actually the / off any address.

Comment: Not necessarily - world addresses are HARD. It's actually a huge problem, with different standards and addresses. It's probably just this one specific address - the Google API is pretty smart, and will figure it out (for instance, 123/A mainstreet) will be 123 Mainstreet, house A, but google maps will just drop the A part.

Comment: @JonLuca Im also using this with the Google Places API. So After I get the latitude & longitude from the Geocode API, I pass those coordinates off to the Places API with a keyword off the place. In this instance I pass the keyword=dominick+pizza&radius=300 but thats the only way I can target the place for now.